# Get item position and string of a List (Android)

Tags: java, android, string, listview, onclick

I need to get in a toast the position and the string of a item in a ListView when is clicked. Until now it only gives me the position, but not the string. I need help getting the string of the same position

This is my code

```
public void mandaOnClick(View v){

    try {
        View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
        lista = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
        final int position = lista.getPositionForView(parentRow);
        //this is not working
        final String item = (String) lista.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //this is not working
        String string = (String) lista.get(position);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Your " + position + string + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is how i set my adapter in my list

```
public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, List<Animal>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Animal> doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        List<Animal> contactos = null;


        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {

            // Establecer la conexión
            con = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setReadTimeout(10000);

            // Obtener el estado del recurso
            int statusCode = con.getResponseCode();

            if (statusCode != 200) {
                contactos = new ArrayList<>();
                contactos.add(new Animal(null, null, null, null));


            } else {

                // Parsear el flujo con formato JSON
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());

                // JsonAnimalParser parser = new JsonAnimalParser();
                GsonAnimalParser parser = new GsonAnimalParser();
                contactos = parser.leerFlujoJson(in);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            con.disconnect();
        }
        return contactos;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<Animal> contactos) {
        /*
        Asignar los objetos de Json parseados al adaptador
         */
        if (contactos != null) {
            adaptador = new AdaptadorDeAnimales(getBaseContext(), contactos);
            lista.setAdapter(adaptador);



        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT:

You're doing it wrong by trying to call onClick method from your ListView's layout declaration. You should attach a onItemClickListener to your ListView in your Activity/Fragment class.

First, implement the OnItemClickListener interface in your Activity/Fragment class. Then set the listener:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

And in the onItemClick method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    String str = (String) adaptador.getItem(position);
}
```

Comment: i'm kind of new in this... Can you write some code please?

Comment: But .... I dont have a array; i am using Json parser in a onPostExecute to populate my list.  

Like this:

  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final List<Animal> contactos) {
       
            if (contactos != null) {
                adaptador = new AdaptaderAnimal(getBaseContext(), contacts);
                lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

Comment: Okay, that's why you should provide more code... :)
Could you provide your activity/fragment code and especially how you set your onItemClickListener and adapter initialization.

Comment: Okay, as far as I can see... you're not attaching the onItemClickListener to your list for catching item click events. Instead, you're trying to call a custom method from your list layout declaration onClick attribute... Which is wrong. ListView is not a button and you should attach the proper listener:
`lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(...));` and then use my code.

Comment: ok thanks. Now i have error in getItemAtPosition . Cannot resolve method

Comment: You're using an ArrayAdapter, right? 
Try to use getItem(position) method.